# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 -> error is showing when for docker-compose up for node+postgres application

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nodes

I am new to docker.
My docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    ports:
    - "5430:5431"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  api:
    build: .
    environment:
      DB_USERNAME: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: postgres
      DB_NAME: TestDB6
      DB_HOSTNAME: db
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
```

what changes can be made to resolve the issue?

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Checked if there was any processes running on port 5432, there were none.

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice that when you encounter an error, you should share the error output along with the configuration that caused it. If I had to guess since there's no error, in the `db` definition you put

```yaml
ports:
 - "5430:5431"
```

And usually, the default port for postgres is `5432`. So you're exposing a port that postgres isn't actually using. Best solution would be to update the ports mapping to

```yaml
ports:
 - "5430:5432"
```

You also could try to configure postgres to run on `5431` instead of `5432`, but that's probably unnecessary.